# transferring a number using serial port

Tags: assembly, serial-port, mplab, pic18

I want to write a program to read a number from dipswitch and transfer that number using rs232 protocol(serial port). this program is written in assembly language. I have used PORTB as an input port and it is connected to dipswitch in order to get the number that is supposed to transmit. I simulated this protocol in proteus but it doesn't show anything as a result. what's wrong?

PROTEUS SIMULATION -

[image: Screenshot]

here is the code:

```
#include<p18f2550.inc>

; CONFIG1H
 config FOSC =HS      ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))

; CONFIG2H
 config WDT = OFF        ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
 config WDTPS = 32768    ; Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)


ORG 0X00
GOTO MAIN

MAIN:
MOVLW B'00100000' ;enable transmit and choose low baud
MOVWF TXSTA ;write to reg
MOVLW D'15' ;9600 bps
MOVWF SPBRG ;write to reg
BCF TRISC, TX ;make tx pin and output pin
BSF RCSTA, SPEN ;enable the serial port
SETF TRISB ;portb defined as input

OVER:
MOVFF PORTB,W ;move portb to wreg
CALL TRANS


TRANS:
S1
BTFSS PIR1, TXIF ;wait until last bit is gone
BRA S1 ;stay in loop
MOVWF TXREG ;load th value to e transmitted
CALL OVER

END
```

Comment: Using so many `CALL` will lead to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CALL` too many times without `RETURN` will cause stack overflow, and it will cause device reset as the message suggests unless `STVREN` bit in `CONFIG4L` register is set to 0.

Not tested, try using `GOTO` instead of the `CALL`s.

```
#include<p18f2550.inc>

; CONFIG1H
 config FOSC =HS      ; Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator (HS))

; CONFIG2H
 config WDT = OFF        ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
 config WDTPS = 32768    ; Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)


ORG 0X00
GOTO MAIN

MAIN:
MOVLW B'00100000' ;enable transmit and choose low baud
MOVWF TXSTA ;write to reg
MOVLW D'15' ;9600 bps
MOVWF SPBRG ;write to reg
BCF TRISC, TX ;make tx pin and output pin
BSF RCSTA, SPEN ;enable the serial port
SETF TRISB ;portb defined as input

OVER:
MOVFF PORTB,W ;move portb to wreg
GOTO TRANS ; **change "CALL" to "GOTO" here**


TRANS:
S1
BTFSS PIR1, TXIF ;wait until last bit is gone
BRA S1 ;stay in loop
MOVWF TXREG ;load th value to e transmitted
GOTO OVER ; **change "CALL" to "GOTO" here**

END
```

Comment: there is no warning now but nothing is shown as the result in the window. its empty

Comment: IDK PIC asm, but couldn't you drop the GOTO from the end of `OVER` and just fall through into `TRANS`?  I assume `GOTO` is an unconditional jump.

Comment: What is the input to `PORTB`? This program will send the input as characters, not decimal numbers. For example, if you send `NUL` (0), it won't appear on the terminal.

Comment: If you single step through the simulation, is the program actually following the path you intend? (I don't know PIC assembly)